# NFC to read the tag and paste the UID where ever we want

Tags: android, nfc, copy-paste, android-cursor, qpython

I have Nexus 7 tablet which is NFC enabled, with using of Android NFC apps in that I am able to read the UID of the NFC tag. But what I want is when the NFC tag is showed to tab UID should copy and it should paste where ever the cursor at that point of time.to do this

- Is there any Android NFC APP which i get from play store for free of cost?
- I should write any script to do this? If I should write a script how can I write with QPython
- Please give me apk if some is developed already.

Please give me full details instead of giving some source link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good tool for this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter

That in combination with the one below are my favorite NFC android tools.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite

These two apks allow you to set up NFC tags with so called NDEF messages. This message contains predefined data structures like contact information and can therefore open a specific app with default intents.

If you want specific automated actions based on an NFC tag you should create an app with the proper NFC intents in the manifest. The documentation is available online with many examples. You have to register your app to react on that type of nfc tags so that it opens when a tag is presented. The app then reads out the uid and handles that information to your liking.

Not sure why we should write this for you. Expect this message to be closed soon if that is your only intent.

Comment: Hi hcpl, thanks for your response, I would like to know is there any app to read the NFC tag ID(UID) and paste in the web browser or in my html form field or paste where the cursor is placed.

Comment: the second link is an app that will read the nfc tag and display the UID (and other information) on screen. You can than manually select and copy paste that where you want.

Comment: With your suggestion i have seen it is very nice app but I want Tag ID should paste dynamically instead of manual copy and paste.